# Typescript Import function gets compiler error

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2017

In my Typescript I am using the import function as described here:

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12933

So my code is like:

```
 import("../myScriptToBeImported").then((module) => {
                this.dosomethingWithModule(module);
            }).catch(this.doSomethingWithError.bind(this));
```

I am running this as part of an MVC project in Visual Studio with Webpack. Webpack compiles the Typescript without any errors and the project runs fine, yet for the above line the following errors are always shown in Visual Studio:

- TS1128   (TS) Declaration or statement expected.
- TS2391   (TS) Function
  implementation is missing or not immediately following the
  declaration.
- TS7010   (TS) 'import', which lacks return-type
  annotation, implicitly has an 'any' return type.

I am using Typescript version 2.4.2. How can I get rid of these errors?

For information, my tsconfig file looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "strict": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [ "es6", "dom" ],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Function-style `import` isn't part of the JS module spec yet. You need to set `module` to `"esnext"` in your `tsconfig.json` to use it.

If you've already done that, the issue may lie with Visual Studio - make sure your project is configured to use the correct version of the TypeScript compiler.

Comment: Hi Joe, the module is already set to "esnext" in the tsconfig.json file. I have edited the question so you can see the whole tsconfig file.

Comment: Hm, strange! That makes me think that either a) VS is not picking up the `tsconfig.json` file, or b) VS is using a different version of the TypeScript compiler.

Comment: Aha - on the project properties, Typescript Build tab, the Typescript version was set to 2.3, so I changed this to 'Latest Typescript Version'. This didn't make any difference until I restarted Visual Studio, and then the errors disappeared on build. If you add to your answer I will mark as correct.

Comment: Oh heck - the errors have come back. No idea why - I did a full build before and they didn't show, but now they are there again! Any other ideas?

Comment: Hm, not sure, I'm afraid ): Might be worth rasing it on the TypeScript GitHub.